# Why do we need hot dark matter?

Tags: mass, astrophysics, neutrinos, dark-matter, galaxy-rotation-curve

Data on galaxy rotation curves suggested that not all the mass in the galaxy is accounted for and we can't observe them directly but remind me again why we need [hot dark matter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_dark_matter) in the first place? Wouldn't these hot dark matter be like neutrinos which are light and fast be evenly spread out in space to form any gravity well at all?

Comment: Indeed, with increasing DM temperature, small scale structure is increasingly suppressed. This is why hot dark matter has been ruled out as the sole DM component and the cosmological standard model is based on cold dark matter. Could you elaborate on what you mean with "the need for HDM"?

Answer (score 1):

We do not need hot dark matter, we need cold dark matter. And the rotation curves are far from the only reason for our need of cold dark matter, please see the tag [darkmatter](/questions/tagged/darkmatter) for more info.